# Prove that if $a \neq b$ then $(a+b)/2 > \sqrt{ab}$

Tags: inequality

I have to prove by contraposition that if $a \neq b$, then $(a + b)/2 > \sqrt{ab}$, where $a$ and $b$ are both positive real numbers.

So I need to prove that if $(a + b)/2 \leq \sqrt{ab}$, then $a=b$.

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 &\leq ab \\
(a + b)^2 &\leq 4ab
\end{align}

I don't know if I started correctly, or what I should do next to get $a=b$.

Comment: Hint: expand LHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(a+b)^2\le 4ab$

$a^2+2ab+b^2\le 4ab$

$a^2-2ab+b^2\le 0$

$(a-b)^2\le 0$

Can you see it from here?

Comment: This means a,b have to be equal, because the square of any number except 0 would be ≥ 0. Thanks !

Comment: @Rewind Well done for getting it. For future posts, it is useful for your readers for you to use Mathjax when you write your posts. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). To begin with, just enclose mathematical expressions with dollar signs. E.g. $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ can be written using `$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$`.

Comment: the square of any number except $0$ would be $>0$;  the square of any real number would be $\ge0$, so we'd have $(a-b)^2\le0$ and $(a-b)^2\ge0$, so $(a-b)^2=0$, so ...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$(a+b)^2-4ab=(a-b)^2$.